# Copy Symbolic link to folder using Java

Tags: java, symlink

I'm looking for a way to copy symbolic link to a directory.
Actually, with my application, I can copy directory to a directory and files to a directory.

I used commons.io.FileUtils library

Here is an example :

```
FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(file, destination);
```

Now, I want to do the same with symbolic link.
For instance, lets say that there is a symbolic link in /home/user/Desktop/mysymlink
and a repository /home/user/Desktop/destination

I want to copy mysymlink to destination.

I tried this :

```
Files.createSymbolicLink(new File("/path/to/symlink").toPath(), new File("/path/to/destination".toPath())
```

But i go this error :

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /home/nemtecl/Bureau/montest
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:94)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:458)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:1058)
    at copyapp.file.CopySymbolicLink.copy(CopySymbolicLink.java:24)
    at copyapp.model.CopyAppModel.copyFile(CopyAppModel.java:68)
    at copyapp.instanciation.SwingApp.createController(SwingApp.java:116)
    at copyapp.instanciation.SwingApp.<init>(SwingApp.java:30)
    at copyapp.instanciation.SwingAppFactory.createApplication(SwingAppFactory.java:8)
    at copyapp.client.mycp.main(mycp.java:29)
```

Can you help me :)?

Comment: Unlike in most command-line commands, you cannot specify a directory as the destination.  You must provide the entire non-directory path of the new link.

Comment: @VGR Perhaps you could explain that further in an Answer, so this Question can be resolved.

Comment: The first parameter of `createSymbolicLink` is the full name of the symbolic link you want to create. That is, the full path of the new symlink you want that is the result of the copy operation. The second parameter is the destination which your existing symlink is pointing at - it's not the destination directory to copy to - this is not a copy operation, it's a create operation.

Comment: I thought that symbolic link is the same as directory/file to so you will move it like ordinary file/dir

Answer (score 0):

Your use of createSymbolicLink has two problems:  as RealSkeptic points out, your first two parameters are reversed (they should not be in the same order as an `ln -s` command); and unlike `ln -s`, the destination may not be a directory, it has to be a full non-directory path.

However, for *copying* an existing symbolic link, you don’t actually want Files.createSymbolicLink.  You want to copy the link itself, which you can do by specifying [LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/LinkOption.html#NOFOLLOW_LINKS) to a regular copy.

From the [documentation of Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29):

> `NOFOLLOW_LINKS`
>
> Symbolic links are not followed. If the file is a symbolic link, then the symbolic link itself, not the target of the link, is copied.

So you want something like this:

```
Files.copy(
    Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/mysymlink"),
    Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/destination", "mysymlink"),
    LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS,
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

(Note that the correct way to obtain a Path is with [Paths.get](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String...%29), or, as of Java 11, [Path.of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String...%29).  There is no reason to use java.io.File.)